# MS SQL query parameter from web

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm brainstorming something and wanted to see if the following is possible in MSSQL:

```
CREATE VIEW
 AS
  SELECT This,That,TheOther
  FROM SomeThing
  Where SomeThing.ID = <Result of http://my.app.com/GetUserInfo?UserID=xxx>
```

The webservice returns a default value if xxx is null, but if it is non-null it returns a user-specific value. The goal is to be able to use views that if run from a query editor, use a default value specified globally. But if it's run from inside a MVC app that passes the userid, the view uses a value specific to that user as the query parameter.

It seems like this ought to be possible, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameters in view definitions (there's hacks to get around it, but generally speaking they're all ugly).

In views, the WHERE is typically "hardcoded" as required to come up with a base set (if required).  Then, you query against that view with additional critiera.

Also note that it's a terrible idea to concatenate a value into a raw SQL string.  Use Parameters instead.  Your code will look something like this:

**T-SQL**

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT This FROM That WHERE Those = 'BaseCriteria'
```

**C#**

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnStr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommantText = "SELECT blah FROM MyView WHERE Field = @Value;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", resultFromYourWebService);
    // open the connection and fill the table here
}
```